# How to allow each set of radio buttons to be selected once?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have done a while loop to get all the questions and answers in my database, but however, I am unable to select only one answer per question by using a radio button.

```
<form class ="formlayout" action = "Test.php" method = "post">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $question = $row['question'];
        $option1 = $row['option1'];
        $option2 = $row['option2'];
        $option3 = $row['option3'];
        ?>

        <?php echo $question ?> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option1"><?php echo $option1 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option2"><?php echo $option2 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option3"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <?php echo "" ?><br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to set the $i variable and use the same radio button name for every question

Comment: hi, can you elablorate on the problem?? are you able to select just one option out of **ALL** the questions? or can you select multiple answers to the same questions??

Comment: As far as i can understand from your code ... you are trying to load all the questions and 3 possible options for every question from which the user can select one. So you need a unique name for the option tags for every question: `$i = 1; <input type=radio name=option[1]/><input type=radio name=option[1]/> <input type=radio name=option[1]/>` and so on for every question

Answer (score 0):

Simply give them the same name:

```
<form class ="formlayout" action = "Test.php" method = "post">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $question = $row['question'];
        $option1 = $row['option1'];
        $option2 = $row['option2'];
        $option3 = $row['option3'];
        ?>

        <?php echo $question ?> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="YourName" value="$option1"><?php echo $option1 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="YourName" value="$option2"><?php echo $option2 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="YourName" value="$option3"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <?php echo "" ?><br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Same name wont work because we have many question. And answers for all the question will be in one group.

Answer (score 0):

I think $i is undefined ,,why don't you simply use some static string as name..
for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="my_radio"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `$i` and incerement it to have different groups of answers, You could change your radio name too, to parse it easily later on:

```
<form class ="formlayout" action = "Test.php" method = "post">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $question = $row['question'];
        $option1 = $row['option1'];
        $option2 = $row['option2'];
        $option3 = $row['option3'];
        ?>

        <?php echo $question ?> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option1"><?php echo $option1 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option2"><?php echo $option2 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $i ?>" value="$option3"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <?php echo "" ?><br>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```